# Merging\Joining three FFMPEG Commands (Drawtext / -filter_complex overlay / anullsrc=channel_layout)

Tags: windows, batch-file, ffmpeg, drawtext

Currently I am using three different commands to create three mp4s only to delete the two "temporary" videos using this code.

```
@ECHO OFF
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=size=1280x720:duration=5:rate=25:color=Black -vf "drawtext=fontfile='GothamRnd-Book.otf':line_spacing=15:fontsize=15:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text=Stack Exchange" "out1.mp4"
ffmpeg -i "out1.mp4" -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=10:y=10" "out2.mp4"
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=48000 -i "out2.mp4" -c:v copy -c:a aac -shortest "out3.mp4"
del "out1.mp4"
del "out2.mp4"
pause
```

The nearest I have come is moving the `anullsrc=channel_layout` into the `-filter_complex` but that results in a long encode that I dont really understand what it is going because if I `ctrl-c` to cancel the batch still creates `out3.mp4` correctly.

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=size=1280x720:duration=5:rate=25:color=Black -vf "drawtext=fontfile='GothamRnd-Book.otf':line_spacing=15:fontsize=15:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text=Stack Exchange" "out1.mp4"
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=stereo:sample_rate=48000  -i "out1.mp4" -i logo.png -filter_complex "overlay=x=10:y=10" "out3.mp4"
```

It seems like this could be streamlined to not create the temporary files.
But maybe this is the only way to do this.  Thank you for any assistance and sorry if the answer is obvious.

Rory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use

`ffmpeg -f lavfi -i color=s=1280x720:d=5:r=25:color=black -i logo.png -f lavfi -i anullsrc=cl=stereo:d=5:r=48000 -filter_complex "[0]drawtext=fontfile='GothamRnd-Book.otf':line_spacing=15:fontsize=15:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2:text=Stack Exchange[vid];[vid][1]overlay=x=10:y=10" -c:v libx264 -c:a aac "out3.mp4"`

Comment: Did this work for you? I error:```[Parsed_anullsrc_0 @ 000002316c8a0b80] Option 'd' not found
[lavfi @ 000002316c89aa80] Error initializing filter 'anullsrc' with args 'cl=stereo:r=48000:d=5'
anullsrc=cl=stereo:r=48000:d=5: Option not found ```

and when I remove the duration option it becomes: ```[AVFilterGraph @ 000001c361d76f40] Unable to parse graph description substring: "]vid];[vid][1]overlay=x=10:y=10"
Error initializing complex filters.
Invalid argument ```

Comment: `]vid]` is a typo. Corrected. `d` in `anullsrc` is a new option. You'll need a recent git build. For older versions, you can add `-t 5` before `-i anullsrc`.

Comment: That works now with the ```-t 5``` option.  Do the ```-i``` inputs all have to defined before anything else?    I've read about ```-map 0:v:0``` for streams but not ```[vid]```.  This must be the ```-filter_complex``` mapping.  Thanks again.

Comment: re: `-i`, strictly no, but it's advised for clarity in commands. `[vid]` inside filtergraphs is a filter pad, See https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#Filtergraph-description

Comment: Great.  Thank you.